# Could not find artifact org.apache.flink:flink-table:jar:1.14.3 in MavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

Tags: java, maven, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to add Flink Table dependency in my POM.xml file and the following is the dependency.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This throws the error Could not find artifact org.apache.flink:flink-table:jar:1.14.3 in MavenCentral (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2)

My flink version is 1.14.3

Below is my full pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>SlidingWindowDeviceStatusJob3</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
    <flink.version>1.14.3</flink.version>
    <kda.version>2.0.0</kda.version>
    <kda.runtime.version>1.2.0</kda.runtime.version>
    <avcms.tlvcodec.version>2.2.1</avcms.tlvcodec.version>

</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <!-- Get the latest SDK version from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bom -->
            <version>1.11.903</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>${kda.runtime.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kinesis_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-kinesisanalytics-flink</artifactId>
        <version>${kda.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-logs</artifactId>
        <!-- scope>compile</scope -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

<plugins>

<!-- Java Compiler -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<!-- We use the maven-shade plugin to create a fat jar that contains all necessary dependencies. -->
<!-- Change the value of <mainClass>...</mainClass> if your program entry point changes. -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
<executions>
<!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
<goals>
    <goal>shade</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<artifactSet>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>org.apache.flink:force-shading</exclude>
        <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
        <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
        <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
    </excludes>
</artifactSet>
<filters>
<filter>
<!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
<artifact>*:*</artifact>
<excludes>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
</excludes>
</filter>
</filters>
    <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>com.amazonaws.services.kinesisanalytics.devicestatus.SlidingWindowDeviceStatusJob3</mainClass>
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: flink-table is just the parent pom for other flink artifacts.

Comment: The given error message abbreviated..please post the full error also in such cases there are other warnings etc.

Answer (score 2):

To use the Table API you need `flink-table-api-java`, plus `flink-table-api-scala_2.12` if you are using scala. If you are also using the DataStream API then you'll also need `flink-table-api-java-bridge` and perhaps `flink-table-api-scala-bridge_2.12`.